# Why spacy pipe is not using multiple threads or processes?

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe("sentencizer"))
s = [u"This is a sentence. This is another sentence."*500] * 10000
from time import monotonic as m


start = m()
for x in nlp.pipe(s, n_threads=-1):
  c = [c for c in x]


print(m()-start)
```

Why in this code example, spacy is not using multi-threading or processing?